# Uso di "quello" improprio o no?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, sentences

Spero che questa domanda sia conforme alle regole di questo sito. Conversavo usando whatsapp con una persona a proposito di un giovane alle prese con i primi giri con il suo motorino. Lo scambio di frasi è il seguente:

1. Persona: "Si sta divertendo molto con il motorino, nonostante il motorino
   vintage :)))".
2. Io: "Quello lo ha definito "bellino"".

Il retroscena è che io avevo parlato precedentemente con il ragazzo che mi aveva definito il motorino "bellino", ovvero una ciofeca (anche se non lo ha detto esplicitamente, perché è un ragazzo sensibile ed educato quando vuole). Il "quello" era riferito al motorino, e nella mia testa volevo esprimere il seguente concetto: "sì, i giri in motorino li trova divertentissimi, ma il motorino lo trova brutto". È per questo che ho messo tra apici la parola bellino. L'altra persona mi ha chiesto: "quello chi?". Forse allora avrei dovuto usare una frase del tipo: "lui lo ha definito "bellino"". Perciò la domanda è: la frase 2 è un errore? E se lo è, che tipo di errore ho commesso? Si tratta di cattiva esposizione? Oppure ho fatto un errore grammaticale?

Comment: Come dice Riccardo, non è un errore grammaticale, ma sicuramente è un “errore” di comunicazione, visto che non sei riuscito a trasmettere il messaggio che volevi (anch'io ti avrei risposto come il tuo interlocutore, o avrei pensato che “quello” si riferisse, un po' altezzosamente, al ragazzo).

Answer (score 3):

Errore grammaticale, non mi sembra; ma nella frase 2 "lo" si riferisce al motorino, ovvero equivale a dire "Quello ha definito 'bellino' il motorino", per cui "Quello", essendo all'inizio della frase, sembra diventare il soggetto del verbo ossia la persona che ha parlato. Da cui la domanda "Quello chi?".

L'utilizzo di "Quello", "Quello lì", "Quello là" per riferirsi ad una persona è uso comune soprattutto nella lingua parlata, anche se poco elegante (in alcuni casi anche dispregiativo).

Tu (mi pare di capire) volevi intendere "Quel motorino" come continuazione della frase precedente.

> "lui lo ha definito 'bellino'"

è sicuramente più comprensibile. Sarebbe stato analogo scrivere:

> "Quello, lui lo ha definito 'bellino'".

In questo caso il soggetto è esplicito ed è chiaro che "Quello" si riferisce al motorino della frase precedente (ma stiamo in pratica utilizzando un [anacoluto](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacoluto))